# How do I replace cells in an array based on some criteria?

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have the cell array:

```
im = {'A+' NaN 'B-'; NaN NaN NaN; NaN 'A+' 'B+'; 'B+' NaN 'A-'; 'B+' NaN NaN; 'B-' 'A-', NaN}
```

from which I obtain:

```
refPoints = find(( any(strcmp('A+', im),2) | any(strcmp('A-', im),2)) & (any(strcmp('B+', im),2) | any(strcmp('B-', im),2)))
```

which gives:

`refPoints = [1;3;4;6]`

Now, I want to loop through `im` so as to invalidate points that are too close (say by a factor of 1), and then replace their corresponding cells with `NaN`.

In the given example, `refPoints 3 and 4` are close, hence should be invalidated. I would thus expect my final result to be:

```
im = {'A+' NaN 'B-'; NaN NaN NaN; NaN NaN NaN; NaN NaN NaN; 'B+' NaN NaN; 'B-' 'A-', NaN}
```

and

```
refPoints = [1;6]
```

I have tried the following code:

```
 for ii = 1: size(im, 1)-1

    if find(( any(strcmp('A+', im(ii,:))) | any(strcmp('A-', im(ii,:)))) & (any(strcmp('B+', im(ii,:))) | any(strcmp('B-', im(ii,:)))))==true ...
         & find(( any(strcmp('A+', im(ii+1,:))) | any(strcmp('A-', im(ii+1,:)))) & (any(strcmp('B+', im(ii+1,:))) | any(strcmp('B-', im(ii+1,:)))))==true

    im(ii,:) ={NaN};

   end

end
```

This however does as expected for the 3rd row but not the 4th row. I do not know what exactly I am doing wrong here, but I have no idea what else to do.

Please any help, suggestions or advice on this is very much appreciated? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problems is very close to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42499753/how-do-i-replace-pixels-that-meet-a-distance-criteria/42511707#comment72176185_42511707), but I hope this slightly different answer will be helpful for you.

You can solve this problem by introducing the state variable `isPreviousToClose` as follows:

```
isPreviousToClose = false;
for ii = 1: size(im, 1)-1

    if (( any(strcmp('A+', im(ii,:))) || any(strcmp('A-', im(ii,:)))) && (any(strcmp('B+', im(ii,:))) || any(strcmp('B-', im(ii,:))))) ...
         && ( isPreviousToClose || (( any(strcmp('A+', im(ii+1,:))) || any(strcmp('A-', im(ii+1,:)))) && (any(strcmp('B+', im(ii+1,:))) || any(strcmp('B-', im(ii+1,:))))))
        isPreviousToClose = true;
        im(ii,:) ={NaN};
    else
        isPreviousToClose = false;
    end
end
if (isPreviousToClose)
    im(end,:) ={NaN};
end
```

The current line is set to NaN, if the next or the previous line is close.

Comment: Thanks @m7913d. It works perfectly. Please can you explain how this works to me, particularly this `isPreviousToClose` stuff ?

Comment: `isPreviousToClose` is true if the previous line is removed. If the current line matches your criteria, it is too close if the previous is to close (i.e. `isPreviousToClose`) or the next line is to close. The last line needs a separate if test, because it is not handled in the for loop (`size(im, 1)-1`).
To understand the program better, it can be useful to run the code step by step using the matlab debugger.